# Replace Data Provider and Scenario with Code using REST API in Acumatica

Tags: rest, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am tasked with replacing a manual procedure in Acumatica with an automated one using the REST API. I have been through the integration guide, but I do not know how to determine the endpoints that match up with the manual process I am replacing. This is so basic, but I cannot find the answer anywhere in the documentation I've read through.

Here is the manual process:

(There are two sides to the process, an Import Synchronization and an Export Synchronization -- but I will just focus on the Export for now.)

1) Go into "Export Scenario" option under integration, and choose the "Available Inventory" Scenario -- then select "Prepare and Export."
2) Go to Data Providers and choose "AvailableInventory" Provider. Then select Export from Synchronization tab.

The end result of this is a CSV file that I take to the POS system and import it there.

So, from the API perspective, I need to go to the Inventory via an endpoint, and select all inventory based on date criterion, and then write that out to a CSV file.

But how do I know what endpoint to use, and how can I ensure I am gathering all of the data in my C# code that we were getting using the data provider and data scenario in the manual process?

I've looked in the documentation, but I don't seem to be able to find this.

Comment: Export scenario is an advanced feature with limited configurability because it's meant to provide export capabilities from configuration wizards that don't require knowledge of a programming language. I wouldn't have thought calling an export scenario and retrieving the matching results from a web service is basic or related to endpoint configuration. Hopefully someone can provide an answer on how to call an export scenario and retrieve the generated file.

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour: Thank you for commenting. That confirms what I am suspecting. If I have to reproduce it in code, I can, but... Is there any kind of a mapping document that tells me where to get the data I need? Or a report of all Endpoints for a screen? It other words, if I am looking at Screen AR3030PL, how do I know what endpoints I could use to access the data I see there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to create an **Endpoint** for the **Export By Scenario** page.
Go to **Web Service Endpoints** (SM207060) page and extend any existing endpoint.
Add a new Endpoint and map it to the Export By Scenario page.
 [image]
Add the Name and Status of the Scenario as a parameter.
 [image]
Prepare and Export is starting long operation, in order to get the correct file you will need to do a get request and check if the Status is completed.
Add action under endpoint and map it to prepareExport action of the graph.
 [image]
Add the Name of the scenario as a parameter of the Action.
 [image]

Now is time for the action.
Below is example code how to invoke the our action on the “Export AP Vendors” export scenario.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/ACU19200/entity/DefaultExt/18.200.001/ExportByScenarios/prepareExport");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"entity\":{\n\t\t\"Name\" : {\"value\":\"Export AP Vendors\"}\n\t},\n\t\"parameters\":{\n\t\t\n\t}\n}",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

As a result, you will get 202 Response Code if everything has been handled correctly.

Now we need to check if the scenario has worked and the file is export.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/ACU19200/entity/DefaultExt/18.200.001/ExportByScenarios/Export AP Vendors");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

As a response to this request you will get the Record of the Scenario, something like below:

```
{
    "id": "730d3b2c-d87f-e411-beca-00b56d0561c2",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": "",
    "Name": {
        "value": "Export AP Vendors"
    },
    "Status": {
        "value": "Processed"
    },
    "custom": {},
    "files": [
        {
            "id": "9479c468-1cfa-4fb5-b8bd-30c10535e525",
            "filename": "Data Providers (Export AP Vendors)\\AP Export Vendor Template.xlsx",
            "href": "/ACU19200/entity/DefaultExt/18.200.001/files/9479c468-1cfa-4fb5-b8bd-30c10535e525"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now you need to take the “id” from the files section and get that file

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/ACU19200/entity/DefaultExt/18.200.001/files/9479c468-1cfa-4fb5-b8bd-30c10535e525");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "",  ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

As a result, you will get the file as application/octet-stream.